# Sibling records in a map table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have some database schema where I have two tables and a map table to define a relationship between my two tables.  The tables are a user table (which for this example I've called Sibling) and an object table where the map table defines what objects the users are related to.  Of course I can easily run a query to get a list of the map table's records by user ID but I also need to get all of the "sibling" records of other users who may be related to the same objects.  I've tried using a common table expression to query the records but I'm running into an infinite loop problem.  I'm not even sure if a CTE is the way I should be going about this problem.  I have set up a SQLFiddle example here.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/289a4/6

So if I query on a sibling ID of 101 I would like to get following set of records.

1   101

1   102

2   101

2   103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required output:

```
declare @Sibling int 
set @Sibling = 101

;with Objects as 
(
      select ObjectId from ObjectSiblingMap 
      where SiblingId = @Sibling
)
,Siblings as 
(
      select ObjectId,SiblingId from ObjectSiblingMap
      where ObjectId in 
      (select ObjectId from Objects)
)
select * from Siblings
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the objects mapped to a specific user easily:

```
SELECT ObjectId
FROM ObjectSiblingMap
WHERE SiblingId = 101
```

Now, to get the users who are related to the same objects as the user 101, you shall use a nested query based on the previous result:

```
SELECT SiblingId
FROM ObjectSiblingMap
WHERE SiblingId <> 101
    AND ObjectId IN
    (SELECT ObjectId
    FROM ObjectSiblingMap
    WHERE SiblingId = 101)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I get a little better performance with the common table expression version.

Comment: @ScottWilson: No, the query generated by CTE will also consist of an outer and an inner query, so theoretically there will be no difference in performance. CTE has advantages (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx), mostly about the maintainability and readability of the code, but performance is not among them.
In my opinion CTE is quite an overkill for such an easy task, but of course it is your task :)

Comment: I get what you are saying.  I went by the execution times of each method to make my decision.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/289a4/34 vs. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/289a4/35 although they seem to vary wildly so I'm not sure how accurate the execution time really is.